# create authentication sub-user in flask-pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I've a flask web app in which I authenticate to the "core" DB as admin.

```py
MONGO_URI = "mongodb://myUserAdmin:abc123@localhost:27017/test?authSource=admin"
mongo = PyMongo(app)
# ... and I am able to interact with the DB
    flash(mongo.db.user.find_one())
```

now, I want to create sub-DBs for each user of the app and let him modify only its specific DB (or table). How can I configure flask to manage that? I tried to look in web but found no solutions.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

Create Authentication middleware

```
class UserAuthenticationMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        '''
            Authenticate the user here
        '''
        self.app.user = {'_id': ObjectId('ddddddddssssssssssss')} #  authenticate the user and get it from db
        return self.app(environ, start_response)
```

Then create a Database middleware to get a db for the user

```
class DbMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        if hasattr(self.app, 'user'):

            # create a database by user id or you can use any unique field here
            self.app.db = self.app.db_client[str(self.app.user._id)]
        else:
            self.app.db = self.app.db_client['default_db']
        return self.app(environ, start_response)
```

Then in create app instance

```
from flask import Flask


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.db_client = MongoClient() 
    app = DbMiddleware(UserAuthenticationMiddleware(app))
    app.run()
```